# Add a new key : value inside a existing dictionary and save that using pickle and then load that dictionary in another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pickle

So basically, I am trying to create a password manager where I can save my email and password.
first I created a dictionary and save it using pickle:

```
import pickle

passDB = {} # this is the dictionary
key = input("Email: ") # taking email
password = input("Password: ") # taking password
passDB[key]= password # assigning new email and password into the dictionary
pickle.dump( passDB, open( "passDB.p", "wb" ) ) # saving it as passDB.p
```

Saved it as add2db.py. Then I created a password manager in python file like this:

```
import pickle
passDB = pickle.load( open( "passDB.p", "rb"))
query1 = input("Search your email account to get password: ").lower()
if query1 in passDB.keys():
    print(passDB[query1])
else:
    print("Nothing such email in database")
```

Saved it as passman.py.
So, the problem here is, Suppose I added a new email and password into the add2db.py file. It adds perfectly. When I try to search password by email in passman.py file, it shows the password perfectly. But again, when I try to add another email and password in add2db.py, it again adds successfully but removes the existing email and password I added at first. And there is no sign of first email and password when I try to lookup using passman.py
Can anyone solve the following?

1. I want a create add2db.py file that keeps adding new email and password to an existing dictionary. The dictionary must contain all previous email and passwords. So that I can look for all the email and password in passman.py

Answer (score 0):

In add2db.py, you need to load your database, add the new email, and then dump it again. Replace `passDB = {}` with `passDB = pickle.load( open( "passDB.p", "rb" ) )`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I was having a sleepless night because of this. I did everything you said, but unfortunately it says:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python projects\PassBook v1\add2db.py", line 4, in <module>
    passDB = pickle.load( open( "passDB.p", "rb" ) )
EOFError: Ran out of input`  What should I do now?

Comment: You probably got this error because passDB.p was empty. you could either do `pickle.dump( {}, open( "passDB.p", "wb" ) )` once when you create the original database, or you could do something like this in add2db.py: `import os
passDB = pickle.load( open( "passDB.p", "rb" ) ) if os.path.getsize('passDB.p') > 0 else {}`